# I cannot leave from while loop of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, review

I am refactoring my code below, before refactoring the code works. I am searching for my mistake with console.log, but I could not find it. Why I cannot leave the loop?

Here is the code

```
const questions = [
        ["ゲーム市場最も売れたゲームは？"],
    ]
    
    const answers = [["SFC", "PS2", "NintendoDS","NintendoSwitch"],]
    
    const correct = [["NintendoDS"]]
    
    let $button = document.getElementsByTagName("Button")
    const setupQuiz = () =>{
        document.getElementById("js-question").textContent = questions[0][0]
    
        let buttonIndex = 0
        let buttonLength = $button.length
        while (buttonIndex < buttonLength){
            $button[buttonIndex].textContent = answers[0][buttonIndex]
            buttonIndex++
        }
    }
    
    setupQuiz()
    
    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        if (correct[0][0] === e.target.textContent){
            window.alert('Correct!')
        } else {
            window.alert('Wrong...')
        }
    }
    
    let buttonIndex = 0
    const buttonLength = $button.length
    console.log(buttonLength)
    
    //The loop is here...
    while (buttonIndex < buttonLength){
        $button[buttonIndex].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            clickHandler(e)
            buttonIndex++
            console.log(buttonIndex)
        })
    }
    
    //I wanna refactoring below
    // $button[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //     clickHandler(e)
    // })
    //
    // $button[1].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //     clickHandler(e)
    // })
    //
    // $button[2].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //     clickHandler(e)
    // })
    //
    // $button[3].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //     clickHandler(e)
    // })
```

Comment: `buttonIndex++` needs to be outside the `addEventListener` call I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this code.

```
while (buttonIndex < buttonLength){
        $button[buttonIndex].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            clickHandler(e)
            buttonIndex++
            console.log(buttonIndex)
        })
    }
```

It will update the buttonIndex when user will click on the button that's why it never changes. You need to move this outside the Event Listener.

I changed this code to

```
while (buttonIndex < buttonLength) {
  $button[buttonIndex].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    clickHandler(e)
    console.log(buttonIndex)
  })
  buttonIndex++
}
```

now it's working fine as expected

---

**Full Code**

```js
const questions = [
  ["ゲーム市場最も売れたゲームは？"],
]

const answers = [
  ["SFC", "PS2", "NintendoDS", "NintendoSwitch"],
]

const correct = [
  ["NintendoDS"]
]

let $button = document.getElementsByTagName("Button")
const setupQuiz = () => {
  document.getElementById("js-question").textContent = questions[0][0]

  let buttonIndex = 0
  let buttonLength = $button.length
  while (buttonIndex < buttonLength) {
    $button[buttonIndex].textContent = answers[0][buttonIndex]
    buttonIndex++
    console.log("here", buttonIndex)
  }
}

setupQuiz()

const clickHandler = (e) => {
  if (correct[0][0] === e.target.textContent) {
    window.alert('Correct!')
  } else {
    window.alert('Wrong...')
  }
}

let buttonIndex = 0
const buttonLength = $button.length
console.log("length", buttonLength)

//The loop is here...
while (buttonIndex < buttonLength) {
  $button[buttonIndex].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    clickHandler(e)
    console.log(buttonIndex)
  })
  buttonIndex++
}
console.log("stopped")

//I wanna refactoring below
// $button[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//     clickHandler(e)
// })
//
// $button[1].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//     clickHandler(e)
// })
//
// $button[2].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//     clickHandler(e)
// })
//
// $button[3].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//     clickHandler(e)
// })
```

```html
<button id="js-question">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop adds an event listener to the button.

Then it adds another one.

Then it adds another one.

And so on, infinitely.

The condition you are testing (`buttonIndex < buttonLength`) **never** changes.

It *might* change if the event listener were ever to be called, but if a click event were to be registered on it, the event handler **won't be called** because the main event loop is **too busy** running your while look to ever check.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the addeventlistener function is not executed in the loop (only executed when you click on the button). So buttonIndex++ is not applied.

You should place it also outsite the addeventlistener function.